# Receive JSON object in Swift Socket.IO Client

Tags: json, swift, socket.io, swift3

How can I receive a JSON object in the [Swift Socket.IO](http://socket.io/blog/socket-io-on-ios/#) client?

**Node.js**

From socket.io on Node.js, I emit a json object as in this simplified example:

```
socket.emit('welcome', { text : 'Hello, World!' });
```

**Swift**

In an iOS Swift client, I would like to get this message out of the object.

```
socket?.on("welcome") {[weak self] data, ack in
    print(data)
    if let msg = data[0] as? String {
        print(msg) // never prints; something's wrong
    }
}
```

The value of `data` when I print it out is:

```
[{
    text = "Hello, World!";
}]
```

When I attempt to parse `data[0]` with the following (from the [Apple Developer Blog](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=37))...

```
let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data[0], options: [])
```

...I am met with an error message:

> Cannot invoke 'jsonObject' with argument list of type '(with: Any, options: [Any])'

Comment: Can you print the response of data and add in the question.

Comment: @ThisClark. I am new to socket.io. Can u please guide me how send parameters for swift socket.io ..

Comment: Beyond the website linked in my question and the Github repository, I found the following TicTacToe source code helpful in writing my first iOS Socket.io app: https://github.com/nuclearace/socket.io-client-swift-example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your data is type of `[[String: Any]]`, get `text` like below.

```
if let arr = data as? [[String: Any]] {
    if let txt = arr[0]["text"] as? String {
        print(txt)
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to map the data to a custom model instead of typecasting every thing and adding manually to the model ?